# JQuery. Как перетащить текст из одного списка в другой?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-n-drop

Есть "block2", в котором есть список из блоков с текстом. Этот текст нужно перетащить в соответствующие блоки в "block1". Т.е. текст из первой строки нужно вставить в первую строку другого блока, вторую — во вторую и т.д. Нужно забирать именно текст без перестраивания и копирования структуры.

Пример разметки:

```
<div class="block1>
    <div class="block1_text"></div>
    <div class="block1_text"></div>
    <div class="block1_text"></div>
</div>

<div class="block2>
    <div class="block2_text">Текст 1</div>
    <div class="block2_text">Текст 2</div>
    <div class="block2_text">Текст 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var text = $('.block2_text');

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    $('.block1_text').eq(i).text($(text[i]).text());
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zo51au32/)

Comment: Как быстро, спасибо! ;))